# Java: string split by regexp to get only integers

Tags: java, string, split

I have a string: `[1, 2, 3, 4]`. I need to get only integers `1 2 3 4`.

I tried the following splits:

```
str.split(",");
str.split("\\D\\s");
```

Both splits return four elements: [1 2 3 4], but I don't need these brackets `[ ]`. What is wrong with split regexp?

**updated**

I had to mention that the case when each number is wrapped with `[ ]` can occur.

Comment: `substring` first. then `split`

Comment: @MustafaGenç, what if each integer is wrapped with `[]`?

Comment: Try yourString = yourString.replace ( /[^\d.]/g, '' );

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could try filtering out unwanted elements first and then split:

```
String filtered = str.replaceAll("[^0-9,]","");
String[] numbers = filtered.split(",");
```

Comment: Oh, really, how could I miss `replaceAll`. Thanks, that is what I tried to do.

Comment: This is possible, but does not allow changing the delimiter easily, with a source like `[1][2],[3]` for example you will run into problems

Comment: For all we know the desired output for ```[0 1,2]``` might as well be ```01 2```. Everything not mentioned by OP is a speculation.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is doing exactly what you tell it: split the string using "," as a delimiter:

```
"[1, 2, 3]" => "[1" , " 2", " 3]"
```

You *could* massage the string into shape before using `split()` - to remove the spaces and the square brackets. However a more direct, regex way to do it is to use a Matcher to scan through the input string:

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)\\D+");
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
    while(matcher.find()) {
        list.add(matcher.group(1));
    }
    // if you really need an array
    String[] array = list.toArray(new String[0]);
```

This pattern `(\d+)\D+` matches one or more digits, followed by one or more non-digits, and it captures the digits in a group, which you can access using `matcher.group(1)`. It matches your input quite loosely; you could make it more specific (so that it would reject input in other forms) if you preferred.

Answer (score 1):

Actually split function returns an array of string,That's why you getting this [].

Use replace method to do this.

Answer (score 1):

The regex that you give to the split method is used to determine the index of each split.

The cleanest solution to handle your case would be using `Pattern.compile` to create a pattern like `[0-9]+` and then use the matcher to find each match in your source string.

Code example:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(yourString);

while(matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

This prints out each consecutive number in `yourString`.

---

*Appendix:* if you use this piece of code often, create a static variable which compiles the Pattern already when loading the class, as pattern compilation is expensive. Like: `private static final Pattern NUMBER_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+");`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
String str = "[1, 2, 3, 4]";
String num = str.replaceAll( "[^\\d,]", "" );
```

you will get String *1,2,3,4*

Then use `String[] allNums = num.split(",");`

**EDIT**:  this will also work for the input `String str = "[[1], [2], [3], [4]]";`

Answer (score 0):

```
String s=s.substring(1,s.length()-1);
String s1[]=s.split(",");
```

this will give you the expected string.

Comment: If each integer is wrapped with [], this won't work.

Comment: @Dragon it that case is possible then you should have mentioned it in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this to the code:

```
yourString = yourString.replace ( /[^\d.]/g, '' );
```

Answer (score 0):

replace the brackets `[ ]`and then split

```
str.replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("\\]", "").split(",");
```

Comment: instead of `"\\["`, it's better to use raw strings: `r"\["`